# Having trouble with basic php if/else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

## This works if 'test1' is in the url:

```
<? if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'test1') !== FALSE) : ?>
  <p>Do something</p>
<? else : ?>
  <p>Do something else</p>
<? endif ?>
```

---

## This doesn't work if 'test1' is in the url:

```
<? if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'test1') OR strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'test2') !== FALSE) : ?>
  <p>Do something</p>
<? else : ?>
  <p>Do something else</p>
<? endif ?>
```

---

## Questions:

1.
When I try to run the second option, php outputs "Do something else" every time - I know it's basic but why is this?

2.
Why doesn't `== TRUE` work in this instance, only `!==FALSE` works.

---

Any help would be much appreciated - I've spent a scary amount of time researching this so sorry if it's because of a dumb mistake.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't test loosely with `== TRUE` because you might get a false positive, remember that `0` is falsy when its tested loose and getting `0` in `strpos` is valid since that actually is the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of your string.

Consider this snippet:

```
<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'test1.com'; ?>
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'test1') == TRUE): ?>
  <p>Do something</p>
<?php else : ?>
  <p>Do something else</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is an example of that false positive.

`test1` is indeed inside the string (position `0`), but since it returned `0` and your testing it with `== TRUE` it will go in the `else` block, leaving out a wrong answer.

So you should always test it `!== false`:

```
<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'test1.com'; ?>
<?php if(
    (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'test1') !== false) OR
    (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'test2') !== FALSE)) : ?>
  <p>Do something</p>
<?php else : ?>
  <p>Do something else</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Actually its in the [manual](http://php.net/strpos) covered. Read the *red box* note.

Comment: Thank you. May I please ask why you set HTTP_HOST to something first - is that just good programming practice? Cheers, Ben

Comment: @CMSCSS no, i just explicitly set `HTTP_HOST` some value for this particular example. glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'test1') OR strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'test2') !== FALSE){ 
  echo"<p>Do something</p>";
} else {
  <p>Do something else</p>
}
```

Comment: don't open, and close php tags as it slows down page processing.